# IF MATCH formula with multiple output possibilities

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet

Morning All, I am trying to check for a value across 2 worksheets and columns.

If the value appears in column E in sheet 1, then return the value. If it does not appear, check in column E in sheet 2. If it appears in sheet 2, then return "account closed", if not then return "does not exist"

I have used an `iferror(if(match` function and can produce the results separately but what I would like is to combine them

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(E2, 'Export Accounts PROD'!E:E,0),Exceptions!E2), "Not in PROD")
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(E2, 'Export Accounts CLOSED'!$E:$E,0), "Account Closed"), "Does not exist")
```

I would like to combine the 2 formulas so that if the first condition is not met, it moves to the second condition rather than returning "not in PROD"

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. The suggested solution below replaces the iferror result in the first formula with the second formula adding the additional iferror to the start to return the "Does not exist" as required.

```
=IFERROR((IFERROR(IF(MATCH(E2,'Export Accounts PROD'!E:E,0),Exceptions!E2),IF(MATCH(E2,'Export Accounts CLOSED'!$E:$E,0),"Account Closed"))),"Does not exist")
```

Comment: Hi Pan, works perfectly !! Thanks so much, this was driving me crazy yesterday :)